# Get list of dates between 2 dates has error

Tags: java, android, date, android-fragments, android-activity

I try to get the list of dates between 2 dates. However, all values in the lists is the start dates.

For example

datefrom = 06-10-2017

dateto  =  10-10-2017

==> all the value of the list is datefrom (06-10-2017)

Expected---------------------------------------Actual

dates[0] = 06-10-2017-------------------dates[0] = 06-10-2017

dates[1] = 07-10-2017-------------------dates[1] = 06-10-2017

dates[2] = 08-10-2017-------------------dates[2] = 06-10-2017

dates[3] = 09-10-2017-------------------dates[3] = 06-10-2017

dates[4] = 10-10-2017-------------------dates[4] = 06-10-2017

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class fragTable extends Fragment{
...
private String mdateFrom = "06-10-2017";
private String mdateTo = "10-10-2017";

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();    
    dates = getDaysBetweenDates(stringToDaTe(mdateFrom),stringToDaTe(mdateTo));
}

 public  List<String> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
{
    List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTime(startdate);

    while (calendar.getTime().before(enddate))
    {
        Date result = calendar.getTime();
        dates.add( datetoString(result));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
 //Convert String to Date  
 public Date stringToDaTe(String dateString)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
  //Convert Date to String
  public String datetoString(Date date)
{
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String result = df.format(today);
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: post that error than

Comment: What is datetoString?

Comment: your question is not clear , what is the expected output? Do you  just want date in between excluding start date and end date??

Comment: Using [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) you can perform this task way too easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `dateToString` method:

```
public String datetoString(Date date)
{
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    String result = df.format(today);       // <= You're actually formatting "today" date, not "date"
    return result;
}
```

By changing that line to

```
String result = df.format(date);
```

Your problem should be solved

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to get the dates between 2 dates.

```
public class test {
    private static String mdateFrom = "06-10-2017";
    private static String mdateTo = "10-10-2017";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dates = getDaysBetweenDates(stringToDaTe(mdateFrom), stringToDaTe(mdateTo));
        System.out.println(dates);
    }

    public static List<String> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate) {
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(startdate);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(enddate)) {
            Date result = calendar.getTime();
            dates.add(formatDate(result));
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        return dates;
    }

    public static Date stringToDaTe(String dateString) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(dateString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

    public static String formatDate(Date result) {
        String date = "";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM/yyyy");
        date = df.format(result);
        return date;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
[06-10/2017, 07-10/2017, 08-10/2017, 09-10/2017]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you print your output i am guessing you use `datetoString()`.

It has

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String result = df.format(today);
return result; // returns always today, not given date
```

Maybe it should have

```
String result = df.format(date) // the input ;
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from java 8
code becomes simpler and lightweight no need to casting back and forth from String . Plus you save yourself from potential timezone issues

```
public List<LocalDate> getDaysBetweenDates(Date startdate, Date enddate)
{
    LocalDate dateFrom  =stringToDaTe(mdateFrom).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate dateTo  =stringToDaTe(mdateTo).toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    long days = Duration.between(dateFrom.atStartOfDay(), dateTo.atStartOfDay()).toDays();
    List<LocalDate> resultList= new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    long i=0;
    do {
        resultList.add(dateFrom);
        dateFrom = dateFrom.plusDays(1);
        i++;

    } while (i < days+1);
    return resultList;      
}
```